# Android: Use TelephonyManager or AudioManager for checking phone state before executing code

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-audiomanager

My question is, what is the best way to get the phone state (is it in call mode), to decide the further way. I would like to check for phone state before deciding whether execute sound notification or not. If I understood right the `TelephonyManager` requires a `BroadcastReceiver` so app can detect when the phone state has changed. But in my app I want to check phone state in one discreet moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a best way because there is only one way, check the call state via TelephonyManager. No need for a receiver:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int callState = tm.getCallState();
```

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_IDLE) for the call state constants.

Comment: Thanks for answer! However i just realised that in my case i want to check not only the phone state, but also if any other speaker-to-ear processes are active (skype etc).